# constructing a JSON object in c#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I want to create a json like this :

> {'sr_no':'OH009876673','data':[{'code':'0124','findex':'3'},{'code':'0126','findex':'5'},{'code':'0125','findex':'8'}]}

I am trying to do it but got error becuase I am using postData as dictinory

**code**

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, string>();
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
axCZKEM1.ReadAllUserID(iMachineNumber);//read all the user information to the memory
axCZKEM1.ReadAllTemplate(iMachineNumber);//read all the users' fingerprint templates to the memory
while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetAllUserInfo(iMachineNumber, out sdwEnrollNumber, out sName, out sPassword, out iPrivilege, out bEnabled))//get all the users' information from the memory
{
    for (idwFingerIndex = 0,i=0; idwFingerIndex < 10; idwFingerIndex++,i++)
    {
        if (axCZKEM1.GetUserTmpExStr(iMachineNumber, sdwEnrollNumber, idwFingerIndex, out iFlag, out sTmpData, out iTmpLength))//get the corresponding templates string and length from the memory
        {

            var obj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            obj["code"] = sdwEnrollNumber;
            obj["findex"] = idwFingerIndex.ToString();
            data[i] = jss.Serialize(obj);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);

var client = new RestClient();
client.EndPoint = @"";
var postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
postData["sr_no"] = sr_no;
postData["data"] = data;  // error on this line because data is array and trying to assign to string
```

How to solve this because I want array of object in JSON to request to API.

Comment: Have you tried using Json.NET? It's generally preferred over JavaScriptSerializer these days.

Comment: will it work in visual studio 2008 or 2010 ? @JonSkeet

Comment: @SaMeEr it works with all versions of .NET - see http://www.newtonsoft.com/json . You might have to manually get the dlls and import them into your project because vs 2008 doesn't really support nuget. the library itself is no problem however, and will work. see also: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NewtonSoft.Json` to serialize object. Since you already have a sample of expected json data, you can generate the c# class on http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Datum
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string findex { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string sr_no { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

And use the class in your code instead creating `Dictionary`

```
RootObject obj = new RootObject();
obj.sr_no = "OH009876673";
obj.data = new List<Datum>();
......
......
while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetAllUserInfo(iMachineNumber, out sdwEnrollNumber, out sName, out sPassword, out iPrivilege, out bEnabled))//get all the users' information from the memory
{
    for (idwFingerIndex = 0,i=0; idwFingerIndex < 10; idwFingerIndex++,i++)
    {
        if (axCZKEM1.GetUserTmpExStr(iMachineNumber, sdwEnrollNumber, idwFingerIndex, out iFlag, out sTmpData, out iTmpLength))//get the corresponding templates string and length from the memory
        {

            //var obj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //obj["code"] = sdwEnrollNumber;
            //obj["findex"] = idwFingerIndex.ToString();
            //data[i] = jss.Serialize(obj);
            //i++;
            obj.data.Add( new Datum() {code = sdwEnrollNumber, findex = idwFingerIndex.ToString()});
        }
    }
}

axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, true);

var client = new RestClient();
client.EndPoint = @"";

var outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Comment: Where should I add that classes ? in main file or in different file.

Comment: In the same file is ok.

Comment: but it is giving me error if i try to add this classes in same file

Comment: add it outside the method in your post

Comment: Obviously I added it outside.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
            var sr_no = "";
            var data =new List<Data>();
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            axCZKEM1.EnableDevice(iMachineNumber, false);
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            axCZKEM1.ReadAllUserID(iMachineNumber);//read all the user information to the memory
            axCZKEM1.ReadAllTemplate(iMachineNumber);//read all the users' fingerprint templates to the memory
            while (axCZKEM1.SSR_GetAllUserInfo(iMachineNumber, out sdwEnrollNumber, out sName, out sPassword, out iPrivilege, out bEnabled))//get all the users' information from the memory
            {
                for (idwFingerIndex = 0, i = 0; idwFingerIndex < 10; idwFingerIndex++, i++)
                {
                    if (axCZKEM1.GetUserTmpExStr(iMachineNumber, sdwEnrollNumber, idwFingerIndex, out iFlag, out sTmpData, out iTmpLength))//get the corresponding templates string and length from the memory
                    {

                        data.Add(new Data { code = sdwEnrollNumber, findex = idwFingerIndex.ToString() });
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            var postObject = new RootObject
            {
                sr_no = sr_no,
                data = data
            };
            var postData = jss.Serialize(postObject);

public class Data
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string findex { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string sr_no { get; set; }
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}
```

also i suggested to use `newtonsoft` instead of `JavaScriptSerializer` .